# Reading data from a model

Tags: python, model, treeview, pyqt

I am working on a PyQt application, which has a TreeView, and data is displayed there using a model. Let me present first the code, and describe then the difficulties I have.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = mainwindow.Ui_uiMainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.root = Node('root')
        self.childNode = ChildNode('child node', self.root)
                self.childNode2 = ChildNode('child node2', self.root)

        self._model = PreferencesModel(self.root, self)
        self.ui.uiTree.setModel(self._model)

        self._propEditor = PropertiesEditor(self)
        self.ui.layoutMain.addWidget(self._propEditor)
        self._propEditor.setModel(self._model)

        self.ui.uiSave.clicked.connect(self.savePreferences)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.uiTree.selectionModel(),
            QtCore.SIGNAL("currentChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)"),
            self._propEditor.setSelection)

    def savePreferences(self):
            pass
```

What I would like to do is to read all the attributes from `childNode` and `childNode2` for example, and save them into a json or xml file in the `savePreferences` method. However, I don't know if I should read (or write) the values using `self.childNode.attribute` or using `self._model`.

Comment: Checkout the [Simple DOM model example](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/itemviews/simpledommodel.py), it basically creates a DOM model for the `QTreeView`